# group child vertices by property

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

I'm using Amazon Neptune with the following simple graph schema:

`root --has--> child`

where the root vertex can have many different properties.

I want a query that creates a dictionary that includes all the root vertex properties as keys and an array of all the child's vertices with the same value.

for example with the following data:

```
{
  root: {
   a: 1
   b: 2
   c: 3
  },
  child1: {
   a: 4
   b: 2
   c: 3
  },
  child2: {
   a: 1
   b: 4
   c: 3
  }
}
```

I'll get the following result:

```
{
  a: [child2],
  b: [child1],
  c: [child1, child2]
}
```

When I know the properties I can do something like this:

```
g.V().hasLabel('Root').as('root')
  .project('a', 'b', 'c')
  .by(out('has').where(eq('root')).by('a').fold())
  .by(out('has').where(eq('root')).by('b').fold())
  .by(out('has').where(eq('root')).by('c').fold())
```

is there a way to create this without knowing the root properties?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's a more elegant solution than this, but that's my attempt anyway:

```
g.V().hasLabel('Root').as('root').
  properties().as('prop').
  group().by(label).
    by(select('root').
      out('has').where(properties().and(
          where(eq('prop')).by(key),
          where(eq('prop')).by(value)
        )).
      fold())
```

example: https://gremlify.com/9y